# Add texture of img1 to img2 to get result img - Python / Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, opencv

I am trying to add texture and pattern of img1 to img2 to get result something like the result image img3 - Img2 is has transparent background and result Img3 must also have transparent background

[Img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlKkh.jpg)

[Img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsQj1.png)

[Img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSs9G.png)

---

Comment: Why is this tagged js/python? Please add more details, take a look at [ask] and [tour].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do a spherical distortion on image 1 to the same radius as that in image 2. Then do a hard light composition blend of that image with your image2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do that in Imagemagick. It can be done in Python/OpenCV, but I do not have the time now to implement it. It is pretty easy in Imagemagick using one of my bash shell scripts to do the spherize of the texture.

*(I show how to do the spherical distortion in Python/OpenCV at [How make eye and nose bigger or smaller in opencv and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69953948/how-make-eye-and-nose-bigger-or-smaller-in-opencv-and-python/70042527#70042527) in a previous post. And an example showing how to do the hard light composite in Python/OpenCV is in [How to augment scanned document image with creases, folds and wrinkles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278790/how-to-augment-scanned-document-image-with-creases-folds-and-wrinkles/64362188#64362188))*

- First, I have to trim the sphere image to its bounds and have it square dimensions.
- Then I have to resize the texture image and crop it to the same dimensions as the trimmed sphere image.
- Then I apply the spherize script to the cropped texture image
- Finally I save the alpha channel from the sphere image and do a hardlight composite of the sphere image with the spherized texture image. And save the result

Sphere Image:

[image]

Texture Image:

[image]

```
convert sphere.png -trim +repage sphere_trim.png

convert texture.jpg -resize 1375x1375^ -gravity center -crop 1375x1375+0+0 +repage texture_resize_crop.jpg

spherize -a 1 -b white texture_resize_crop.jpg texture_resize_crop_spherize_a1.jpg

convert texture_resize_crop_spherize_a1.jpg \
sphere_trim.png \
\( +clone -alpha extract +write mpr:alpha +delete \) -alpha off \
\( +clone \) \
-compose hardlight -composite \
mpr:alpha -alpha off -compose over -compose copy_opacity -composite \
sphere_texture.png
```

Trimmed Sphere Image:

[image]

Resized and Cropped Texture Image:

[image]

Spherized Texture Image:

[image]

Result From Hardlight Composite:

[image]